# error on updating com.google.gms:google-services version from 4.1.0 to 4.2.0

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I am updating the dependencies in my android project. It is a multi-module project with clean architecture. 
I have updated all the firebase library versions but whenever I change the com.google.gms:google-services the version from 4.1.0 to 4.2.0 Gradle sync fails with error code 1.

**Here is the log of the IDE errors --**

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at com.google.android.gms.dependencies.DependencyInspector.registerDependencies(DependencyInspector.java:118)
    at com.google.android.gms.dependencies.DependencyInspector.afterResolve(DependencyInspector.java:173)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor103.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:370)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:352)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)


2019-03-30 21:54:24,345 [ thread 70]   INFO - System.util.ExternalSystemUtil - External project [/Users/d/C/A] resolution task executed in 4840 ms. 
2019-03-30 21:54:24,345 [ thread 70]   WARN - ect.sync.idea.ProjectSetUpTask - 1 
2019-03-30 21:54:24,345 [ thread 70]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed: 1
```

**Project level Gradle file --**

```
apply from: 'buildsystem/dependencies.gradle'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

buildscript {\
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        //maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools' }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.9.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6"
    }
}

allprojects {
    ext {
        androidProductionApplicationId = '****'
        androidStagingApplicationId = '****'
        androidVersionCode = 264
        androidVersionName = "3.0.0-beta"
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.host.url", "http://sonar.****.com/"
        property "sonar.login", "*****"
        property "sonar.projectKey", "android_test"
        property "sonar.language", "java"
        property "sonar.sources", "src/main"
    }
}
```

**App level Gradle file ---**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

repositories {
    google() //google's maven repo to use firebase and other google services
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    jcenter()
}

android {
    def globalConfiguration = rootProject.extensions.getByName("ext")

    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'MyReleaseKey'
            keyPassword '****'
            storeFile file('../buildsystem/keystore.release.jks')
            storePassword '****'
        }
        debugconfig {
            keyAlias 'MyDebugKey'
            keyPassword '****'
            storeFile file('../buildsystem/keystore.debug.jks')
            storePassword '****'
        }
    }

    compileSdkVersion globalConfiguration.getAt("androidCompileSdkVersion")
    buildToolsVersion = globalConfiguration.getAt("androidBuildToolsVersion")

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId globalConfiguration.getAt("androidProductionApplicationId")
        versionCode globalConfiguration.getAt("androidVersionCode")
        versionName globalConfiguration.getAt("androidVersionName")

        minSdkVersion globalConfiguration.getAt("androidMinSdkVersion")
        targetSdkVersion globalConfiguration.getAt("androidTargetSdkVersion")

        multiDexEnabled true

        defaultConfig {
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
            }
        }
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        resConfigs "en"
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules-presentation.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            resValue 'bool', 'GHOST_ENABLE', "false"
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debugconfig
            resValue 'bool', 'GHOST_ENABLE', "true"
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "default"

    productFlavors {
        staging {
            applicationId globalConfiguration.getAt("androidStagingApplicationId")
            resValue 'bool', 'CAN_CHANGE_HOST', "true"
        }
        production {
            applicationId globalConfiguration.getAt("androidProductionApplicationId")
            resValue 'bool', 'CAN_CHANGE_HOST', "false"
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }

    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
}

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.java.binaries", "build/intermediates/classes/staging/debug"
    }
}

dependencies {
    def presentationDependencies = rootProject.ext.presentationDependencies
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation project(':data')
    implementation project(':domain')
    implementation(presentationDependencies.crashlytics) {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation(presentationDependencies.multidex)
    api(presentationDependencies.gson)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.gcm)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.fcm)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.jsoup)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.mixpanel)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.facebook)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.branch)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.cardview)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.recyclerview)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.fab2)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.design)
//    implementation(presentationDependencies.appindexing)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.eventbus)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.exo)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.firebaseauth)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.firebasedatabase)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.firebaseconfig)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.firbaseinvites)
    kapt(presentationDependencies.daggerCompiler)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.rxAndroid)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.rxJava2)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.rxAndroid2)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.butterKnife)
    kapt(presentationDependencies.butterKnifeCompiler)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.adapterDelegates)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.firebaseCore)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.fresco)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.frescoAnimatedGif)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.volley)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.dagger)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.isoparser)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.kotlin)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.lifecycle)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.appCompat)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.facebookShare)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.placeAutoComplete)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.googlePlayServiceAuth)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.realmAdapters)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.socketIo) {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    implementation(presentationDependencies.lifecycleExtensions)
    kapt (presentationDependencies.lifecycleCompiler)
    implementation(presentationDependencies.constraintLayout)

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: please add your build.gradle to the question

Comment: Added Gradle file please check

Comment: @Diwas, check if this explanation helps and you would like to check if your module is also using gms. https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/issues/22#issuecomment-462058903